# If $|G|=p^2$ and $p$ is prime then $G\simeq \mathbb Z_{p^2}$ or $G\simeq \mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb Z_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $|G|=p^2$ where $p$ is a prime. How can I show $G\simeq \mathbb Z_{p^2}$ or $G\simeq \mathbb Z_p\times \mathbb Z_p$?

Notice $|G|=p^2$ implies $G$ is abelian however I still can't use the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups but I can use the Sylow's theorems.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

What are the possible orders of elements in $\;G\;,\;\;|G|=p^2\;$ ?

What if $\;G\;$ isn't cyclic, i.e. if $\;G\neq C_{p^2}\;$ ?

Comment: Do you really mean that $G\neq C_p\times C_p$ is equivalent to "$G$ isn't cyclic," or are you misusing "i.e." here?

Comment: It should be $G\neq C_{p^2}$. It's clearly not $C_p$...

Comment: These aren't hours to do mathematics, obviously...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take any $x \in G$. Then order of $x$ divides $p^2$ and hence order of $x$ is either $p$ or $p^2$. If order of $x$ is $p^2$ then $G$ is cyclic and hence has to be $\mathbb{Z_{p^2}}$. Otherwise all elements of $G$ must have order $p$. Now, choose an $x$ and take $y$ such that $y$ doesn't belong to the group generated by $x$. Show that $x$ and $y$ generate $G$.

Comment: I think you mean "any $x\in G-\{1\}$"?

Comment: of course Nishant.